# How to bind functions which accepts types from external libraries

Tags: pybind11

I am trying to bind a function which accepts Gst Buffer as follows

```
 some_function(GstBuffer *buffer)
 m.def(some_function,&some_function);
```

binded it using the above code, when called from python it says

some_function accpets args0:_GstBuffer type, it doens't accpet a python type of Gst.Buffer object.

I have tried to put 
       GST=py::module::import('gi.repository.Gst') but it didn't work, is there any other way to resolve this problem. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind function which accepts type uknown to pybind you can *pass* it as generic `py::object` argument.

```
m.def("some_function",
     [](py::object obj){
         ... 
});
```

Now can use python interface of the passed `py::object` in your function. But I guess it's not what you want to do on C++ side.

The problem is in *conversion* from python-wrapper-around-c++-object to pure-c++-object.

pybind doesn't know the layout of passed wrapper and unable to extract pure C++ part from python object. This is true when you are using types which are binded NOT by pybind (such as `gi.repository.Gst`).

To get the C++ part of `py::object` you need to know where C++ part resides. You either need to do it manually or with help of another binding library.